# Can we find a relation between the three integrers $m$, $j$ and $k$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, real-numbers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $r>4$ and $n>1$ positive integers and let $α$ be a positive real number.

Let us define the following three positive integers:
$$
\begin{align*}
m &= \lfloor r^{(n+1)^2} \alpha \rfloor \\
j &= \lfloor r^{(n-1)^2} \alpha \rfloor \\
k &= \lfloor r^{n^2} \alpha \rfloor
\end{align*}
$$
where $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ is the floor function.

My **question** is: Can we find a relation between the three integers $m$, $j$ and $k$?

I know that $j<k<m$. I want to see relations of the form: $m=bk,k=cj$,..etc.

Comment: If the floor function weren't there, you would have $r^2k^2=mj$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible because m, j, and k are all not linearly related. Consider this definition:
$$
m=r^x$$$$
j=r^y$$$$
k=r^z
$$
Since $x \neq y \neq z$, these variables can't be related through multiplication by a constant. This is equivalent to trying to represent a quadratic equation as a linear equation, which is clearly impossible.